# Execute query according the position into a table (cell)

Tags: php, mysql

I write a table with the following code and need to do a second query when click on any result (cell) on table:

```
 while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
 {
 $id = $test['id']; 
 echo"<td>".$test['name']."</td>";
 echo"<td><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#add_new_record_modal' class=text-dark>".$test['open']."</a></td>";
 echo"<td><a href='#' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#add_new_record_modal' class=text-dark>".$test['close']."</a></td>";
 echo "</tr>";
 }
 mysql_close($conn);
 ?>
```

The result are the folowing table:

```
+--------+----------+----------+
|  Name  |   Open   |   Close  |
+--------+----------+----------+
| user1  |     0    |     1    |
| user2  |     3    |     0    |
| user3  |     2    |     1    |
| user4  |     0    |     3    |
| user5  |     1    |     1    |
+--------+----------+----------+
```

Actually I open a new window with this:
For example click number **3** on Row 2 (**user2**) and Column 1 (**Open**) and need to get the variable that contains exactly the name of Row 2 and Column 1:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="add_new_record_modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">

<?php
include("conn.php");

//$result = mysql_query("Select * from table where stat = '$column_1' and name = '$row_2'
$result = mysql_query("Select * from table where stat = 'Open' and Name 'user2'");**

while($test = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
    $id = $test['id']; 
    echo"<div class='form-group'>";
    echo"<label for='s'>".$column_1." ".$row_2."</label>";
    echo"</div>";
    }
    mysql_close($conn);
?>
</div>
```

How can I replace "**Open**" and "**User2**" for the correct variables?
thanks!